# zpl 2 is not printing turkish characters

Tags: java, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I need to print special Turkish characters with zpl 2 codes. I create my zpl String and send it to the print server. But Turkish Characters are not printed. My code is below. I added a font that has Turkish characters. In printed document it ignores characters prints TESTTEST. Do i need to look to encode my zpl string or what ?

```
        zpl.append("^XA");
        zpl.append("^MMT");
        zpl.append("^PW812");
        zpl.append("^LL0812");
        zpl.append("^LS0");
        zpl.append("^CI35");
        zpl.append("^FT40,230^A0B,23,31^FH\\^FDTESTÖİÜŞıöüşçÇTEST^FS");
        String zplString = zpl.toString();

            Charset charSet = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-9");
            byte[] ptext = zplString.getBytes(charSet); 
            String value = new String(ptext, charSet);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you print out the contents of ptext in decimal or hex? Also you have zpl.append but fill ptext from zplString. Are there missing steps in there where zplString is filled from zpl?

Comment: No i did not add these lines of code. Now i updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code

^XA

^CI28

CI28 is support Turkish characters :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you use the charset ^CI28  (UTF-8 encoding),  instead of ^IC35, it could work. At least it looks like checking with http://labelary.com/viewer.html

Comment: I used CI35 according to [zpl 2 proggramming guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) page 130. It indicates that CI35 is used for  Code Page 1254 encoding and it incules Turkish Characters.